# how to update checkbox value as checked in salesforce using lwc

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

how to update checkbox value as checked in salesforce org record by using lwc

ex: I have a req that if the **A** field (checkbox) value as true then the email alert will send. This **A** checkbox should be updated via LWC Javascript file (because this is a hidden field I have) so I need to set the value of the Checkbox as true in onclick function. after that this value(checked) should update in salesforce record.

Comment: What have you tried? what doesn't work?

Comment: You should utilize the apex controller to do the update in the cloud.